# Making a row editable, need graph based on checkbox in HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-3.x, bokeh

I have a df!
Now based on the data in the df I want to present a HTML page where

1. one column of each row will have an editable textbox. This textbox will show a particular data from the df and this will be editable for the user.
2. There will be a update button which will update the new entry for the column of the row.
3. I also want checkboxes in from of each row which will be clickable and based on which checkboxes are clicked there will be bokeh plotting on a graph.

Now I have managed this with js and python where I have used

```
        DataTable(selectable='checkbox',
                               source=column_view_data_source,
                               columns=columns, fit_columns=False, width=1650,
                               height=400, css_classes=['blueTable'])
```

in js I have

```
        CustomJS(
            args=dict(name_dict=name_dict_mos, source=column_view_data_source),
            code=callback_file_content_mq)
```

But I am unable to install a editable textbox in this solution.

Please help!
P.S. I need to have a solution in python HTMl and JS combination